# Windows 7 Enterprise lost the ability to switch users

Tags: windows-7, switch, users

One of our laptops runs Windows 7 in a work-group (rather then domain), and recently, it lost the ability to switch users.

I mean, the "Shut down -> Switch user" just doesn't appear there, and locking user, doesn't show the "Switch user" button.

I tried disabling/enabling the "Hide entry points for Fast User Switching", with no visible effect.

Anyone knows what this could be?

Comment: Have a look at [this SuperUsers-Question](http://superuser.com/questions/263962/fast-user-switch-compatibility-service-missing-in-windows-7-prof-domain-member)? Look for the mentioned service `fast user switch compatibility service`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you use **Windows key + L** combination to switch users?

Or you can go to Command Prompt and use this command to log off/switch between users.

**shutdown -L**

Comment: Unfortunately, this only logs me off, while I need the user switching functionality.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is that your machine has lost the Fast Switching functionality. Perhaps this link would help,

http://krypted.com/uncategorized/enable-fast-user-switching-for-windows-command-line/

Comment: Browse to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon in the registry and then change the value of the AllowMultipleTSSessions key to REG_DWORD of 1 (or back to 0 to disable). Very similar to how it works in Mac OS X. If you want to script this (eg – for a login script) then you can use the reg command, for example:
reg add “hklm\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon /v AllowMultipleTSSessions /t REG_DWORD /d “1″ /f

Comment: Thanks, will try (still have it somewhere in our office un-handled after all this time :) )